# How to perform smoothing operation in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Let say I have an image in RGB form and I applied MATLAB command `rgb2hsv` to convert it to HSV form.

Now I want to apply smoothing filter to saturation matrix (that we get from output of `rgb2hsv`).

How can I apply smoothing filter? Which command to use? Is it okay to use `filter2` command?

Comment: The first part of the question is irrelevant. The second part can be researched trivially and rely depends on your needs. Have you actually tried anything and run into problems, or are you asking for someone to write your project for you?

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
hsv=rgb2hsv(img);
H = fspecial('disk',10);
hsv(:,:,2) = filter2(H,hsv(:,:,2),'same');
```